# Defining different log4j2.xml configurations based on environment

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2, environment

I want to try and use logj 2 in my web application.  With log4j 1.x, we set-up different configuration files based on environment and use ServletContextListener to load the appropriate configuration using a call like

> DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(logConfigFile, delay);

by passing the config file location.

I was planning on doing the same for log4j2 config file but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716556/how-to-specify-log4j-2-x-config-location) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778986/log4j-only-can-view-error-level-on-my-java-enterprise-application-module-ejb-wi), it is not possible or advisable to use DOMConfigurator with log4j2.

So, my question is: How can I use different configuration files based on environment with log4j 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Remko Popma, I posted the question and got an answer from log4j user mailing list.  One can use a System property or environment variable with 'log4jconfiguration' context-param to dynamically set the configuration file at runtime

Comment: Is it possible to share the post or comment? I have a similar use case i am trying to solve

Comment: This (http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Defining-different-log4j2-xml-configurations-based-on-environment-td40639.html#a40662 is the post that I have mentioned in the reply

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve with having multiple config files? I'll take a guess that you want to have separate log files for each web application.

One way you can achieve this is using  the RoutingAppender; this can delegate log events to other appenders depending on key/values set in the ThreadContextMap. Some people use their web app name as the value to switch on.

Beta-9 (the last beta before GA) will be released soon and it will have better docs for using log4j2 with web apps (and the FAQ will have a detailed RoutingAppender example).

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for the response. No, here I am not trying to have separate logfiles for each web application, but a separate config file for each of the environments, so that, for example, I can have DEBUG in dev and UAT, but not in PROD or can have large file sizes in dev and uat, but not in prod. Like I mentioned in the question, what we do with version 1 is that we have, say, log4j-dev.xml, log4j-prod.xml etc. and have a servlet context listener and an env variable such that without making code changes, when I deploy the app to an env, it picks up correct config

Comment: I see. This may already be possible, otherwise you can request this as a new feature. Either way you probably want to raise this on the user mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Servlet 3.x container, I would recommend going with what Log4j2 recommends by adding the log4j-web jar to the others being used and setting the Context Parameters as stated in the log4j2 [usage manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) for web applications.

Answer (score 0):

The mailing list link in the answer is broken. Although it is currently accessible [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/201309.mbox/%3C01D31688-3DD5-4B8A-8BD1-BAEFC0FBD93B@dslextreme.com%3E).
For a full answer, you can use a system property in the context param like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:/${sys:MYLOGDIR}/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This one was really hard to find as it is only mentioned in the mailing list.